# What does this parameter type constraint mean?

Tags: c#

I am looking at some code and I don't understand what a particular constraint means in the following class definition:

```
internal abstract class Entity<T> : Entity
    where T : Entity<T>
{ ... }
```

I don't understand what this implies about parameter type `T`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is similar to the "[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)" (but it is NOT the same).

It can be used (among other things) to help constraint the parameter types of methods in a derived class to the same type as the derived class itself.

[Here's an interesting blog post from Eric Lippert on this subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx).

The main use of this is to force classes that derive from `Entity<T>` to implement some method that accepts a parameter of the same type as the deriving class.

In the following code sample, we declare in the `Entity<T>` class a method `DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe()` which accepts a parameter of type `T`.

Because of the generic constraint, this will force any classes that derive from `Entity<T>` to implement a version of `DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe()` which takes a parameter of the deriving class type.

This is of limited use, and it is very confusing to read, so I agree with Eric Lippert when he says you should avoid such code!

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var test1 = new Derived1();
            var test2 = new Derived2();

            test1.DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe(test1);
            test2.DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe(test2);
        }
    }

    public class Entity
    {
        public string Hello()
        {
            return "Hello, World.";
        }
    }

    public abstract class Entity<T>: Entity where T: Entity<T>
    {
        public abstract void DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe(T item);
    }

    public sealed class Derived1: Entity<Derived1>
    {
        // You are forced to implement DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe() with a param type "Derived1".
        // (i.e. the parameter is the same type as 'this')

        public override void DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe(Derived1 item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing something with a Derived1 item: " + item.Hello());
        }
    }

    public sealed class Derived2: Entity<Derived2>
    {
        public override void DoSomethingWithTheSameTypeAsMe(Derived2 item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doing something with a Derived2 item: " + item.Hello());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't you confuse C++ templates with C# generics?

Comment: Isn't the principle the same for C#?; the important thing is that the type is constrained in that way.

Comment: I agree, this answer isn't correct. In CRTP, the base class is generic as well which isn't the case here. And if you say `Base<Derived>` is the same as `Entity<T>` here, you are also incorrect, because in C# you can't access the members of the derived class in base this way.

Comment: Is it not related? Eric' Lippert's blog post seems to say this, but it's very subtle - so subtle, I guess I *could* have confused the terminology. Should I perhaps say that it's a *variant* of CRTP?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The base class in this example is generic if we assume the base is `Entity<T>` from the perspective of `T` due to the self-referencing constraint. `Entity` has no bearing in this. Though I agree with the rest of your comment.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I am not really sure why Eric calls his sample of `class Blah<T> where T : Blah<T>` a variation of CRTP. If I understand CRTP correctly, in C++ it is about giving `Base<Derived>` access to the members of `Derived`. But in his sample, the constraint `where T : Blah<T>` is about ensuring that a parameter is of a certain base class. To me this looks like different things. I can only think of one reason why he would call it a variance of CRTP: If a method on `Blah<T>` would return `T` the *caller* would have access to the members of the derived class.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: That's exactly what I am thinking, too.

Comment: Not quite. By the constraint, you ensure that the compiler knows that T is a Blah<T>, hence you can call T.methodOfBlah without dirty casts. THerefore, for me, it is a kind of CRTP, as you gain "access" to those methods on T

Comment: Example: `public class Blah<T> where T : Blah<T> { public T WithFoo() {...} }` and a derived class like this: `public class DerivedBlah : Blah<DerivedBlah> {...}` and a usage like this: `new DerivedBlah().WithFoo().MembersOfDerivedBlahAccessibleHere();`.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: The point about CRTP - at least according to the comment in the sample on wikipedia - is to not give access to `methodOfBlah` but to give access to methods of the derived class. This is not possible in C#. In `Entity<T>` you can only access methods of `Entity<T>`, not of `DerivedEntity`.

Comment: It is not truly CRTP, because it does not 100%ly work at the level of Blah itself. It works in combination where you desing a Blah<T>/T:Blah<T> as a base class to be derived from, and where you then derive from it:  Foo : Blah<Foo>. Firstly, it allows the base to treat the T as its own type, and also it gives the base an exact static knowledge of T. Hence, Blah<T> can define "T MyField{return ???;}" that returns the final type. Therefore it resembles a CRTP from the outer point of view:the base is able to RETURN a T type that matches the child. It is, really, a weak similarity, but still some.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: If I understand you correctly, what you are saying in this comment is basically the same as I said in the last part of my comment and illustrated with my comment with the example. After all those comments I am actually no longer sure that the answer really is incorrect. But it still isn't getting an upvote because I have the feeling it doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm going to try to add a concrete example to show why it can be useful. I agree that it's only related to CRTP.

Comment: I was writing that comment while you were writing yours, and had to split the text, so please don't be mistaken by the timing. Please treat both of my comments as one big first comment :) I fully agree with your example code and reasoning, that's what I meant. I wanted to say that both the syntax and that the fact that the-base-that-just-knows-the-final-type is what resembles CRTP. By "not quite" I mean: the Child:Base<Child> which forms the usual use case for such Base<T> is very like CRTP. But, of course in C# you could also `Child : Blah<Child>{} and Kid : Blah<Child>` which is very unlike.

Answer (score 12):

<sub>Although I commented,  I'm going to stick my oar in because I want to also note on what the base type gets from this.</sub>

Simply: `T` must inherit `Entity<T>`.

It's a kind of self-referencing generic often used such that the base class can contain the derived class **type** (via `T`) in methods and other areas. It simply avoids you having to cast stuff or use a base reference in derived types. It can be quite useful, though I rarely see it used in our code.

I will note that this does ***not*** mean the base class can suddenly access derived members. It can still only see the lowest known type defined by the constraints, if they exist. If no constraints exist, `object` is the lowest known type. The benefit is from the perspective of the derived type and the cleanliness it grants on code that is pushed into a base class.

In your case, it would see `Entity<T>` and `Entity` members. This is the reason for constraints.

A standard usage would be something like:

```
public class Customer : Entity<Customer>
{
}

public abstract class Entity<T> 
    where T : Entity<T>
{
    public T Clone(T entityToClone)
    {
        return default(T); // Clone code here, returns derived type.
    }
}   


// Grants you...
Customer clonedCustomer = currentCustomer.Clone();

// Instead of...
Customer clonedCustomer = (Customer)currentCustomer.Clone();

// Ignore ethical constraints on cloning customers and definitely do not tell your sales team that you can ;-)
```

Answer (score 4):

It says that T must be of type `Entity<T>` or derives from that type

Though it seems paradoxical it's valid and can sometimes be useful too, though the cases are rare and often can be handled in different easier to undertand ways.

It's often refered to in C++ lingo as the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

In C# the capabilities are somewhat more restricted than when using the pattern in C++ The concrete classes of this patter will typically look like this

```
class MyClass<ItemType> : Entity<MyClass<ItemType>> {
  //...
}
```

or simply

```
class MyClass : Entity<MyClass> {
   //...
}
```

one example of when this might be useful is when working with attributes on the type.

Say you are creating a list of widgets at run time. The list includes all types that derives from `Entity<T>` and you populate the information based on meta data from attributes. In `Entity<T>` you can handle this once and for all

```
void RegisterWidget(){
  var attributes = typeof(T).GetAttributes();
  //do what ever you need to
}
```

this would of course work with out the constraint but it might still make sense from a functional perspective or to show intend and it might be needed in other parts of the code

Comment: Why the DWs? there's nothing incorrect in this answer and it answers the question

Answer (score 2):

It says that `T` must be or inherit from `Entity<T>`, which is what has the `T` that you're restricting. Obviously `T` can't be an `Entity<T>` because that's abstract, so it must be something that inherits from it.